# How to specify folder for build definition in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I have a single repository, hosted in VSTS, that contains two projects - a frontend SPA and a backend API.

I want to create separate build definitions for each.

When I go to "Create new build definition", I have an option to select the Repository source (the Team Project in VSTS), but I can't see how to specify which folder to set for each project

Comment: Are you using Git or TFSVC?

Comment: Can you select a project with my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple build definitions can have the same repository source. So, In your example, one build definition could build your frontend project and the other build definition can build your backend API project.  Inside each build definition, you will create a task where you specify the required project to build.  For .NET, this will probably point to the .csproj or .vbproj.  For other solutions, you can just point to the folder or whatever is required for your build task.

Answer (score 2):

> > I have an option to select the Repository source (the Team Project in VSTS), but I can't see how to specify which folder to set for each project

In this step, you just can select repository, so you just need to select a repository, after that, you can select project file for Build solution step.
[image]